# Share content between Wordpress sites in a network?

Tags: wordpress

I have five different websites set up using Wordpress 3.0 Multisite. They each contain one page in common, which is a list of places. Each place is represented by a post in a specific category. What I want is that when I publish a new post in this specific category on one blog, it will add that post to all the other websites as well. Alternatively, all websites pull their information from one single blog.

I don't really care how this is done, as long as I don't have to type in the same thing five times :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RSS: [FeedWordPress | simple and flexible Atom/RSS syndication for WordPress](http://feedwordpress.radgeek.com/) or [WordPress › SimplePie Plugin for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simplepie-plugin-for-wordpress/) or [Developer's Guide - Google AJAX Feed API - Google Code](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxfeeds/documentation/)

Answer (score 1):

[Multipost MU](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multipost-mu/) has a nice interface, and can be set to publish to all sites by default.

Comment: Just wanted to comment that the developer no longer supports this plugin and it is also no longer available for anyone viewing this post.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin - [Diamond Multisite Widgets](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/diamond-multisite-widgets/) - that allows you to push new posts to other sites in a multisite network.